# Cannot delete bot app from service plan

Tags: azure, botframework, azureportal

I tried to delete bot app from service plan but have only rainy cloud and disabled delete button: [image: delete page]

Steps to reproduce: open azure portal, click on service plan, click on settings-apps, click on [bot name], click on delete button.

Comment: Things like this happen in Azure Portal from time to time. It's, however, much better nowadays. Just add a support ticket with them from the portal and they'll fix it for you quickly.

Comment: This site isn't Azure tech support, and you should never include your subscription id here (I removed it from your question, along with your bot service name). This looks like a portal glitch (try opening in a private/incognito browser window). But... not a programming question, and off-topic.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thank but I opened this question after request from Azure support in twitter. They told me that is the way to notice support engineers about my problem. And I tried this action in several browser (Firefix, Chrome, Edge) with the same result.

Comment: @Max - whoever told you this is wrong: StackOverflow is not a Microsoft-managed website, and definitely not a Microsoft tech support site: you cannot talk with support engineers here (unless they just happen to be answering a programming question), and you should absolutely not be publishing your subscription id here. What you posted is specifically a portal glitch. Likely transient. And not programming-related.

Comment: If someone on Twitter told you to post a question to StackOverflow, then great, but it's for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation the best thing to do is contact azure support like was said in the comments. The best way to do that is through the portal. I don't think the Twitter support is able to follow up as easily. If you can provide them a network trace, it will help the engineers track down the issue better.